# Code gets only executed once - Phonegap & Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm writing an app that keeps track of your position while running.
The issue is that I can only start/stop the tracking only once. I have to kill the app to restore functionality.

```
$("#startRunning").live('click', function () 
{
    watch_id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( function (position) 
    {
        tracking_data.push(position);
        element.innerHTML = 'Aantal metingen: ' + aantalMeetingen;    
    },
    function (error) 
    {    
        console.log(error);  
    },
    {   
        enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 7000, 
    });

    track_id = loopNummer;
});

$("#stopRunning").live('click', function () 
{
    window.localStorage.setItem(track_id, JSON.stringify(tracking_data));
    alert(watch_id);

    //Reset the values and clearWatch
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watch_id);
    aantalMeetingen = 0;
    watch_id = null;
    tracking_data = null;
    showResult();
});
```

I have no I idea how to fix this issue, because my code (should) be working normally.

Comment: If this is something you're writing now, you should stay away from methods that have been deprecated for some time, like live().

Comment: And what do you suggest as alternative? $("lllelel").click(function()) ?

Comment: Just replacing live() with on()? Gonna try that, 1 moment

Comment: The syntax is different!

Comment: Do you declare any of those variables somewhere, or are they just implied to exist, and all global ?

Comment: They were global declared, but the on() changed nothing (even with the correct syntax). The answer from @mrhobo solved it. Appearantly the function can't work with nullpointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but instead of

```
tracking_data = null;
```

try

```
tracking_data = [];
```

otherwise `tracking_data.push(position);` is bound to cause a null pointer error.

Let me know :)

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it. I never thought of it. Great work!

Comment: np ;) A decent debugger would've told you the same though. Might be worth investing in..

Comment: I was thinking about doing that. Which one do you suggst/use yourself?